# Passing object types to Oracle stored procedure gives "Invalid name pattern" error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle Database administrator provided me a stored procedure. It takes (IN) varchar and supplies  RECORD type. Record type is as follows:

```sql
TYPE BAL_RECORD_TYPE IS RECORD
(
  ac_no               VARCHAR2 (50),
  Account_type        VARCHAR2 (50),
  ac_status           VARCHAR2 (10),
  cur_code            VARCHAR2 (5),
  available_balance   NUMBER
);
```

I've followed the link below to support RECORD type in my jdbc application. 
    http://betteratoracle.com/posts/31-passing-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

From above article I've changed

```java
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "RECTYPE");
```

to

```java
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "BAL_RECORD_TYPE");
```

as BAL_RECORD_TYPE is my RECORD name.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
invalid name pattern: APPADMIN.BAL_RECORD_TYPE
```

Here APPADMIN is username of the database. I don't know how is it binding with OUT parameter.

My questions are:

1. Is there any good example code that I can follow to support RECORD type of oracle?
2. What is the possible reason of the error (invalid name pattern: APPADMIN.BAL_RECORD_TYPE)?

**Addition:**

3. How difficult would it be to implement CURSOR type instead of RECORD type for my oracle database administrator?

Comment: The title of that article is misleading. There's a significant difference between a schema-level object type, and a PL/SQL-defined record type. You can't use a PL/SQL type for a STRUCT as far as I'm aware, even if you include the package name it's defined in as part of the name (`APPADMIN.PKG.BAL_RECORD_TYPE`), you can only use schema-level types..

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for changing title of the article?

Comment: "Passing object types ..."? I can see why that terminology might have been used I think; but they have specific meanings, and having an object called 'recType' is itself confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. Actually, it was not in my part. Our oracle DB administrator defined type inside package which is not accessible from JAVA.

Here is the excerpt: 
We can't call a type which is defined inside a package in ORACLE. Java can't access this type, but sqlplus can access. So, our DB Administrator finally defined the type outside of the package.

I've found this solution from here:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/34668-array-as-out-parameter-java-sql-sqlexception-ora-06550-line-1-column-7

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass a PL/SQL RECORD type to a stored procedure, or fetch it from a stored procedure with JDBC directly. But you can use this trick here to work around this limitation:

```
DELARE
  rec APPADMIN.BAL_RECORD_TYPE;
BEGIN
  my_proc(some_input, rec);
  ? := rec.ac_no;
  ? := rec.account_type;
  ? := rec.ac_status;
  ? := rec.cur_code;
  ? := rec.available_balance;
END;
```

You can now call your procedure as follows:

```
try (CallableStatement s = con.prepareCall(" ... above PL/SQL code ...")) {

    // Register each of your record's individual attribute types:
    s.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(5, Types.NUMERIC);

    s.execute();

    // Fetch each of your record's individual attribute types:
    String acNo = s.getString(1);
    String accountType = s.getString(1);
    String acStatus = s.getString(1);
    String curCode = s.getString(1);
    BigDecimal availableBalance = s.getBigDecimal(1);
}
```

[I've recently blogged about this technique more in detail](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/). The blog post also contains further info about how to automate this technique if you have many procedures / functions taking `RECORD` type IN/OUT parameters.